# Flash Player not working for certain websites in Debian 7.5

Tags: debian, adobe-flash

I'm trying to use a website that uses Flash Player for instant video podcasts.
Flash Player usually works, but when I'm trying to visit the page I get the following message:

> express install is not supported on this operating system to upgrade please visit flash player download center

I have flash player nonfree from the Debian 7 repo, *and* I've tried downloading from the website, but still no luck...

Comment: Example page, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest, Adobe-supported version of Flash for Linux is version 11.2.  This was initially released several years ago and some websites now require a newer version.

The latest version of Flash for Linux (version 14.0 as of mid 2014) is maintained by Google and comes standard with Google Chrome (not Chromium).  In many cases where Flash doesn't work with Firefox or Chromium, you can successfully view the content on Linux with Google Chrome.